# How to load data from a .htm file with google apps sciript

Tags: html, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I set up a automated job via SAP (SM36) where I recieve a report as an attachment on a regular basis via e-mail (GMail). This is working fine but I just received an .htm file from SAP so that I need to transfer the data into a google or excel sheet. Unfortunately, it is not possible to receive the file directly as a .xlsx file.

I know how I can get the .htm file out of gmail into my drive via GApps Script. The next step is to get the data out of this file into a google spreadsheet. I wasn´t able to figure out how I can do this so I ask you to help me with this regard.

How can I get the data out of the report (.htm file) into a google spreadsheet or directly into a excel sheet via Google Apps Script?

Many thanks in advance!

Best regards,

Comment: You can parse it with [xml service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)

Answer (score 1):

1. [search(query)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery)
2. [getMessages()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getmessages)
3. [getAttachments()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getattachments)
4. [getDataAsString()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment?hl=en#getDataAsString())
5. [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)
6. [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I worked with these informations but I struggle to understand the parsing part.

Isn´t there an easier way? After I started a empty GSheet I just can click on "import" and then I can choose the .htm file. After that it is imported and it works fine. That is very easy. But I need to do it via Apps Script so that I can do it automatically.

Comment: If you want to compare coding with a product. I cannot provide you any help.